# better way to limit properties of a field in aggregate call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am trying to perform an `aggregate` call in MongoDB to lookup a collection but at the same time limit how much data I get from the other collection. Here's my attempt that kind of works:

```
getFamilyStats: function (req, res) {
    Families
        .aggregate([
            { $match: { 'centralPath': req.body.centralPath }},
            { $lookup: {
                from: 'models',
                localField: 'centralPath',
                foreignField: 'centralPath',
                as: 'models'
            }},
            { $unwind: '$models'},
            { $project: {
                'models.openTimes.user': 1,
                '_id': 1,
                'centralPath': 1,
                'totalFamilies': 1,
                'unusedFamilies': 1,
                'oversizedFamilies': 1,
                'inPlaceFamilies': 1,
                'families': 1
            }}
            ]
        ).exec(function (err, response){
            var result = {
                status: 200,
                message: response
            };
            if (err){
                result.status = 500;
                result.message = err;
            } else if (!response){
                result.status = 404;
                result.message = err;
            }
            res.status(result.status).json(result.message);
        });
},
```

So the thing that works pretty well is the fact that I can use `lookup` to "join" data from a different collection, in this case called models. Once I `unwind` it it pretty much looks like I want it with the exception that I am only interested in one field from that property: `models.openTimes` and in this particular case actually just one property of that field `user`. I tried to use `project` to limit hom much of data i pass through from models, but that forces me to spell out all other fields like so:

```
_id: 1,
centralPath: 1....
```

That's not ideal in case that my collection ever expands with new properties. I am looking for a way to limit data from `models` to just that one field/one property, but get all fields from `families` collection.

Ideas?

Sample data for families:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae08c75d132ac4442520672"),
    "centralPath" : "some path",
    "totalFamilies" : 0,
    "unusedFamilies" : 0,
    "oversizedFamilies" : 0,
    "inPlaceFamilies" : 0,
    "families" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Sample data for models:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae08c74d132ac4442520638"),
    "centralPath" : "some path",
    "openTimes" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 8123,
            "user" : "ks",
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-04-25T14:11:00.853Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ae08c74d132ac444252063a")
        }
    ],
    "synchTimes" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 208649,
            "user" : "ks",
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:42:42.933Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ae0b0028c2e3b192a3e9dc5")
        }
    ],
    "modelSizes" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 21483520,
            "user" : "ks",
            "createdOn" : ISODate("2018-04-25T14:11:00.787Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ae08c74d132ac4442520639")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with MongoDB v3.6 you can limit the fields returned by a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) directly:

```
db.families.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'centralPath': 'some path' } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'models',
        let: { centralPath: '$centralPath' }, // remember the value of the "centralPath" field
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$centralPath',  '$$centralPath' ] } } }, // this performs the "join"
            { $project: { _id: 0, 'openTimes.user': 1 } } // only retrieve the "openTimes.user" field
        ],
        as: 'models'
    }},
    { $unwind: '$models'},
]);
```

Comment: Good descriptions and better and short option to achieve the goals.
+1 for your logic :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 and above version.

`$addFields` to return the only field from joined collection while keeping existing fields and `$project` with exclusion to drop the joined collection data.

Replace the project stage with addFields and project stage.

```
Families.aggregate([
 existing stages,
  {"$addFields":{
    "user":"$models.openTimes.user"
  }},
  {"$project":{"models":0}}
])
```

Comment: Hi veeram can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586276/mongo-query-distinct-with-sum-is-not-working